# Does OpenMP 4 use OpenCL?

Tags: opencl, openmp, gpgpu

The new OpenMP 4 library now allows to use accelerators such as GPGPU.
Is OpenMP 4 implemented on top of OpenCL for these kind of tasks?

Comment: I Google the title of your question, and found [this](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1211/1211.2038.pdf).  It does not appear to suggest that the two are interrelated.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: interesting article, but it has been published in 2012, maybe written the year before, when OpenMP 4 did not exist, yet.

Comment: Still, I didn't find anything else that suggested the two are related in the way that you describe.  Is there an actual problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: I just wanted to know if the GPGPU part of the new OpenMP 4 had to written from scratch, or if a lower level library such as OpenCL was used. If the second option was true, then it could even be possible to make OpenMP and OpenCL work together.

Comment: An OpenMP 4 implementation could certainly make use of OpenCL if it wanted to, but it's not a requirement of the standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases, yes. See [TI's OpenMP Accelerator Model runtime implementation](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/OpenMP_Accelerator_Model_Getting_Started) as an example. This is due to the fact that OpenCL is a mature standard with significant infrastructure. OpenMP accelerator support is new in version 4.0, so vendors are scrambling to add support.